# Finding a Non-Ascii Character With Rfind - ü

Tags: python, string, parsing, find

So I am trying to find a given character that occurs within an extracted binary's buffer. This extracted binary's character happens to be a u with an umlaut over it. How would I go about finding this character, as python throws the error when i try to run the script of 'Non-Ascii Character in File', the relevant location of the failing file and then 'but no encoding declared'.

```
positionoflastu = ssidstring.rfind('ü')
tvname = ssidstring[lastu+1:]
```

Many Thanks

Comment: With which encoding is your .py file saved?

Comment: I don't know? It's definitely the umlauted u that is causing it to fail.

Comment: It's a module developed as part of the autopsy framework.

Comment: If I try this code in idle 3.7.3 it just works. And the default encoding for Python code is UTF-8 so there is no need to declare it.

Comment: It also states, after the line number, that 'but no encoding is declared'

Comment: May try "\u00FC" instead of "ü"

Comment: That doesn't work, the string is as follows - cý:y<
      üLG TV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like Python is complaining about your .py file, not your data file. The full error message might be something like:

```
SyntaxError:
Non-ASCII character '\xfc' in file foo.py on line 1,
but no encoding declared;
see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

You should read that PEP. It'll tell you that your Python file needs to declare its encoding. You've said that you don't know the encoding of the file, so that'd be a good thing for you to learn how to find out. In the mean time, we could make a reasonable guess based on the specific byte that the error message complains about (which is an example of why it's generally a good idea to include full error messages when you ask a question on StackOverflow).

E.g., if the error message complains about `\xfc`, then your file is probably encoded in Latin-1/ISO-8859-1/CP 1252. If it complains about `\c3`, then your file is probably encoded in UTF-8.

So you could probably get past this error by putting one of

```
# coding=cp1252
```

or

```
# coding=utf_8
```

as the first or second line of your Python source file.

Comment: Thanks, this was what i used to solve it initially, the adding of the utf8 coding block. :)